# Unhide the hidden columns that are extracted to excel from SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS report and certain columns are hidden when we extract to EXCEL.

I am able to hide it in excel by setting the expression for column visibility

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",True,False)
```

But is there a way user can unhide the column in excel (extracted result set) and see the data ?

Answer (score 2):

If items are hidden then in the exported excel file they don't exist.
To make items in excel conditionally visible you can (for example) add two textboxes as follows:
[image]

Then in the second textbox (which you want to hide in excel) you set visibility "can be toggled", use for toggle first textbox and set default state (in my case it's hide, in your case you can write you expression to hide only for excel).

[image]

Then in the excel you will have:

[image]

*PS. I expanded this item after opening (by default it was collapsed).*